# How to assert only if the property to assert is not empty?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

How can I `Hibernate` validate a property that may also be empty? And more important: only validate IF the property is not empty, otherwise SKIP the validation?

```
private int age;
@AssertTrue(condition = "age != null") //something like this
boolean isAgeValid() {
     return age >= 0;
}
```

Is there any possibility?

Comment: Could you also use the `@NotNull` annotation as well?

Comment: `return age == null || age >= 0`? Am I missing something? Which property are you talking about?

Comment: I ONLY want it to be validated if it is `!= null`. I'm using this on a Hibernate Validator to auto-validate all my fields. But if a field is still null/empty, this means the user did not touch it, and thus it should not by validated, as it also may be empty. BUT if it is not empty, it SHOULD be asserted. So I also cannot use `@NotNull`, because it MAY be empty.

Comment: Please define "it". *What* must be non-null? Give an understandable example.

Comment: "it" is of course the variable, eg `age`. I only want a member variable (or moreover a getter using the variable) to be validated if the variable is not null. And I want to skip validation if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm ok, as there is no possibility to overcome this on annotation level, I changed it to the following:

```
@AssertTrue
private boolean isAgeValid() {
     return StringUtils.isBlank(age) || age >= 0;
}
```

Probably the best choice by now.